# How wso2 api manager add custom header to a request passing to backend

Tags: api, wso2, wso2-api-manager

I have created an API in WSO2 API Manager and I want to add a custom header when API gateway receive the request and set the custom header to the API and pass it to back end.
for example when API gateway receive the request for every request of this type adds "My-Header : xxxxx"  to the request and pass it to back end.

How is it possible ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an [in-sequnce](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/) as below:

```
<sequence name="test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"> 
<property name="<NAME>" value="<VALUE>" scope="transport"/>
<property name="<NAME>" value="<VALUE>" scope="transport"/> 
</sequence>
```

Comment: I uploaded a test.xml including <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="test">
   <header name="IDENTITY" scope="transport" value="xxx"/>
</sequence> in publisher portal , message mediation section, I expected wso2 adding this header to the calling api and send it to back end, but when api calling with out the given header, back end throwing exception which means the header not found but when I add the header from client side the api woks fine. I think the wso2 apim does nothing on the header

Comment: i also tested with <sequence name="test" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"> 
<property name="IDENTITY" value="xxx" scope="transport"/>
</sequence> but result was same!

Comment: I fixed the problem as you answered but my  mistake was that I test the API in the publisher environment , I published the API, then in the developer console key I have got API key and it worked fine. thank you

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve this via various methods as mentioned below.

1. **Publisher portal:** If you want to add a custom header along with the request itself, you can add it as follows in the publisher portal.
   [image]
2. **Via custom mediation:** If you want to add the custom header in the gateway component, you can use either a [custom sequence](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/) built using a [header mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/header-Mediator/). This is appropriate to be used if your requirement is simple and doesn't have any complicated logic to be addressed. If you want to add the custom header to a specific API, then you can add the custom mediation only to that API. In case if you want to add it to all the APIs as a global solution, then you can add it as a [global sequence](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/#creating-global-extensions).
3. **Via custom handler:** If you have a complicated requirement in adding the custom header and if you want to add the header in the gateway component, you can use a [custom handler](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/#writing-a-custom-handler) to achieve this.

Answer (score 3):

You can use a [custom sequence](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/api-gateway/message-mediation/changing-the-default-mediation-flow-of-api-requests/) or [header mediator](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/references/mediators/header-Mediator/) for this purpose.

From a long term perspective, you can write a [custom handler](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/develop/extending-api-manager/extending-gateway/writing-custom-handlers/#writing-a-custom-handler) for your specific goal.